# Pivoting duplicate data from rows to columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, duplicates, pivot

I have a dataset with duplicate values due to number of feedback received for a particular candidate.

There are 3 feedback types are Security, Others and Social.

A candidate can have multiple of these feedback. And this feedback type name has to be taken by joining  Org and orgtype table. But this gives me duplicate values in my result set.

The query with few columns is like this:

```
select 
    c.id  as [Candidate ID]
    ,c.name as [Candidate Name]       
    ,cf.status as [feedback status]
    ,e.name as [Feedback Type]
from
    Candidates c
left join
    Candidate_Feedback CF ON CF.CandidateId = c.ID
left join
    Organizations d on CF.OrgId = d.ID
left join 
    OrganizationTypes e on d.OrganizationTypeId = e.Id
```

How can I pivot data where I need only one row for each candidate and feedback types in columns instead of rows? ( Such as **col1 - Feedback_social**, **Col2 - Feedback_Other**, **col3 - Feedback_Security** , col4 - **'N/A'** (if feedback not present)

Due to other scenarios in my query I need these 3 columns for each candidate.

Answer (score 0):

You could use using conditional aggregation, like:

```
select 
    c.id  as [Candidate ID],
    c.name as [Candidate Name]       
    max(case when e.name = 'Social' then cf.status end) [Feedback Social],
    max(case when e.name = 'Other' then cf.status end) [Feedback Other],
    max(case when e.name = 'Security' then cf.status end) [Feedback Security]
from Candidates c
left join Candidate_Feedback CF ON CF.CandidateId = c.ID
left join Organizations d on CF.OrgId = d.ID
left join OrganizationTypes e on d.OrganizationTypeId = e.Id
group by c.id, c.name
```